# play framework+morphia doesn't work with mongodb replset

Tags: mongodb, playframework, playframework-2.2

I use play framework+morphia+mongodb. It works fine when mongodb is running wihout replset. However,when I set up mongodb replset with play framework, i got "com.mongodb.MongoException: not talking to master and retries used up" exception. How can i fix this so play framework can work with mongodb replset?

[image]

Play Framework

```
2.2.6
```

Mongodb Version

```
2.6.5
```

mongod.conf for all 3 mongodb instances

```
dbpath=/var/data/mongodb
logpath=/var/log/mongod.log
port=39068
nohttpinterface=false
fork=true
replSet=cluster
```

rs.conf from 192.168.1.1

```
{
"_id" : "cluster",
"version" : 2,
"members" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : 0,
        "host" : "localhost.localdomain:39068"
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : 1,
        "host" : "192.168.1.2:39068"
    }
    , 
    {
        "_id" : 2,
        "host" : "192.168.1.3:39068",
        "arbiterOnly" : true
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks a bit strange to see localhost mentioned in a replica set configuration as it will resolve to 127.0.0.1 on all machines. I don't know for certain, but my guess is that your client is trying to connect to itself and not 192.168.1.1 (which I guess is the master).

MongoDB provides a [tutorial](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/change-hostnames-in-a-replica-set/) on how to change the hostnames in a replica set. Try following it changing localhost.localdomain to 192.68.1.1.